# Best Rails App Backup Method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys, I'm shopping around for a backup approach for a rails app(with mysql database), I've noticed there's a couple out there like the backup gem, and a few more. Anyone know of any good approaches to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup is better always, have used and is simple to implement. Does all what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of links below which can help you taking your Rails application backup

http://johntopley.com/2009/09/14/back-up-your-rails-application-to-the-cloud

http://storecrowd.com/blog/rails-backups/

http://backupmyapp.com/ (If you are willing to pay)